# Write csv file with non-numeric columns quoted and no row names

Tags: r, csv, quotes

I'm trying to write a csv file from a data frame, i.e:

```
Col_A    Col_B    Col_C
Hello    World    4     
Once     More     21
Hi       Data     23
```

So far I use this code:

```
ds = dataf
write.csv(ds,"test.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = c(1,2), sep = ",")
```

However, the result is:

```
Col_A,"Col_B","Col_C"
Hello,"World",4
Once,"More",21
Hi,"Data",23
```

But I really need to have something like this:

```
"Col_A","Col_B","Col_C"
"Hello","World",4
"Once","More",21
"Hi","Data",23
```

Note that everything is between double quotes unless the numeric values, separated by commas. I can do that if I also write the rownames, but I really don't want them.

Comment: May I ask why you care if the numbers are not also quoted?  Presumably who/whatever consumes this CSV file will know that quotes are only there to escape the column value.

Comment: Sure! The numbers cant be quoted because I'm processing the csv files to load it into a Knowledge Base of ProbLog, where all string informatations needs to be quoted and numbers do not.

Comment: It looks like you may have a working solution below.  Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I did tried it. However, the first colunm is not between double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no point in setting a "set" to "," because it's the default for write.csv.
Anyway, are you sure of your data.frame design ?
This seems to work :

```
df <- rbind(c("Hello", "Once", "Hi"), c("World", "More", "Data"), c(4,21,23))
df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
write.csv(df,"test.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = c(1,2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, the problem remains. The first colunm is not written with double quotes.

Comment: Did you try with my sample code ? If yes, the issue is somewhere else, because on my computer, the result file is sahped the way you want.

Comment: Yes, I tried with your solution and the same issue still remains. I didn't thought about it, but now that you have say that, I also start to think that the problem is somewhere else

Comment: From my dataframe ?

Comment: The thing is that the problem must be associated to my excel porgram because qhen I run your code, but write the dataframe to a txt file, it work just fine, but not in excel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162812/discussion-between-mrsmithgoestowashington-and-joao-fernandes).

Comment: The names(ds) output is:
    [1] "Col_A"    "Col_B"    "Col_C"